# Widget does not appear in widgets as it should be

Tags: android, android-widget

I have developed an android app that has a widget as well. The problem is that when i install the app to my device, the widget is not visible in the widget tab as it should be (I am using android 4.0.3). Widget works fine in the emulator. However if i reinstall the app to my device, widget is available. Can anyone explain this strange behaviour? Any wild guesses?

The code could be found here : [Widget has a weird bahaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096518/widget-has-a-weird-bahaviour)

Comment: Confused why you opened a new question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Widget has a weird bahaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096518/widget-has-a-weird-bahaviour)

Comment: the behaviour is different in that one. The widget is unresponsive there. In this occasion, the widget is not even available in the widget's list (widget tab for android 4.0.3). There must be something in the way I define android manifest or in my code. Also, it might be the case that widget is not visible every time i update versionCode. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

AFAICT, you need to have an activity, and the user must launch that activity before your `<receiver>` element will be recognized by the system. This appears to be an outgrowth of the larger "no `BroadcastReceiver` will work until the app is manually launched" change introduced in Android 3.1.

Comment: So ,you suggest that it might be the case that i have tried to install the widget before opening the using the application?

Comment: @JustCurious: Yes. I have occasionally seen where this was not required for some reason, but I have not been able to reproduce the steps that cause the app widgets to appear by any other means than launching an activity. It may be that, as you suggest, a reinstall automatically moves the app out of the stopped state. If so, that's not going to be especially useful in production, though it may be useful during development.

Answer (score 1):

This is happened when your application is installed in the SD card. In that case, you don't see your application in the widget list. You have to go to settings->apps->your_app and then move that into the phone (internal memory). Now you can see the widget in your widget list.

Cheers !!!
Chanaka

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this is a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24208).

The "run an activity for it to show" described by @CommonsWare was a nice "Workaround" for Honeycomb, but it does not work on ICS.

**The only way I found to work around it in ICS is to go to settings > apps > Launcher and "stop" it.**

Alternatively you could reboot your phone.